# Is there an easier way to write this Haskell Parsec parser for 8-bit decimal integers?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I wrote the following `Parsec` code to decode text that represent `Word8` (unsigned 8-bit integers):

```
decOctetP = try e <|> try d <|> try c <|> try b <|> a
    where
        a = fmap (:[]) digit
        b = do
            m <- oneOf "123456789"
            n <- digit
            return [m, n]
        c = do
            char '1'
            m <- count 2 digit
            return ('1':m)
        d = do
            char '2'
            m <- oneOf "01234"
            n <- digit
            return ['2', m, n]
        e = do
            string "25"
            m <- oneOf "012345"
            return ['2', '5', m]
```

I can't help but feel there is an easier way to do this. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: I think that you're trying to put too much logic in your parser. In the same way that you wouldn't write a regex to only parse numbers between 0 and 255, I think that you should just take any 1 to 3 digit number, and use 'real code' to validate what you've parsed.

Answer (score 7):

Honestly the easiest way is just to parse it as natural number and then fail to parse if it's beyond the bounds 0-255 by returning mzero.

```
import Control.Monad

import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String (Parser)
import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as Tok

natural :: Parser Integer
natural = Tok.natural lexer

number :: Parser Integer
number = do
  n <- natural
  if n < 256 then return n
  else mzero
```

Comment: I'd like to fail on numbers such as 012 though. Would this still work?

Comment: Why would you like to fail on 012? Could you just check that the first digit is not zero?

Answer (score 1):

You could replace `c`, `d` and `e` with something like this:

```
decOctetP = try c <|> try b <|> a
where
    a = fmap (:[]) digit
    b = do
        m <- oneOf "123456789"
        n <- digit
        return [m, n]
    c = do
        m <- (:) <$> oneOf "123456789" <*> count 2 digit
        guard $ combine m <= 255
        return m
    combine = foldl' (\r d -> 10 * r + (ord d - ord '0')) 0
```

Still not very pretty, but it's a little shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up with this version which I think is clean and intuitive:

```
decOctetP = choice [e, d, c, b, a]
    where
        a = fmap (:[]) digit
        b = sequence [oneOf "123456789", digit]
        c = sequence [char '1', digit, digit]
        d = sequence [char '2', oneOf "01234", digit]
        e = sequence [char '2', char '5', oneOf "012345"]
```

Comment: Mark your answer as the solution if you feel it answers your question.